# Deleting first line of a variable if it contains specific string in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm running a program and writing its output into a variable like this;

```bash
var=$(/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand)
```

And this is the output of the command;

```bash
$ /usr/bin/someProgram someCommand
12345
```

So in this case my `var` equals `12345`.

However, sometimes its output can be like this;

```bash
$ /usr/bin/someProgram someCommand
test
12345
```

which as you can see includes the word `test` before the result I need. In this case my first code gets broken because now my `var` equals:

```
test 
12345
```

I need to remove the word `test` from the result so my `var` can be `12345` again. I tried the following code but it didn't work as I expected;

```
var=$(/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand)
var=$(printf '%s\n' "${var//test/}")
```

Because now if I run a command like this;

```bash
$ /usr/bin/someProgram someCommand $var
```

It doesn't work because it's trying to run the above command like this;

```bash
$ /usr/bin/someProgram someCommand     <-- # notice there is a space here and 12345 is given below but it is supposed to be given right after someCommand
12345
```

`-x` output shows there's actually a space before the `12345` after removing the string `test` from it;

```bash
+ var='
12345'
```

another `-x` output for the latter example;

```bash
++ '/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand
12345'
```

I don't know how this space is happening but I guess I need to remove it for this to work and I don't know how.

Comment: What about `var=$(/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand | grep -v test)`?

Comment: Honestly, that just works for me. Thanks :D

Comment: Your example is wrong, there is no newline because you are not quoting the value. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash string substitution to anything followed by `\n`:

```bash
var="$(/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand)"
echo "${var##*$'\n'}"

12345
```

Comment: @MarryJune: Did this work out?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the REAL output is always in the last line:

```
var="$(/usr/bin/someProgram someCommand | tail -1)"
```

With the advantage that it will remove any leading lines.